# Compare 3d objects (wavefront OBJ) programmatically to verify if they are the same geometry

Tags: c++

I am using C++ to compare 3d models of molecules; but I am having hard time to figure out exactly what would be the best way to do so.

I did start reading the OBJ as text file, reading line by line inside an array, and then doing the same with the second object to see if they are the same. I did take inspiration from image comparison; where I read about common algorithms that involve transforming the image in a bytestream and use openCV2 to create histograms and a 2d matrix to compare the 2 images.

Is there another way, that is more appropriate, and allow me to compare models, even if they may have for example, different materials associated to it? All that I am concerned is the geometry, to be sure that it is the same molecule.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'same'? Does the geometry have to be bitwise-equal? Somewhat equal up to a given absolute epsilon? Equal up to an arbitrary scale factor? Equal up to an affine transformation? Equal when a human looks at it and says 'Yeah, they look about the same'?

Comment: And what about rotations etc

Comment: Don't obj files separate geometry from texturing, surface normals, etc? Should be straightfoward to just pull out the vertices and compare those, if that's all you care about.

Comment: So, by "same" I mean exact same object. I am aware that different position of the object in space would produce a different set of coordinates in the OBJ file; although a teapot is still a teapot, even if the vertices are pointing somewhere else, making one teapot parallel to the floor for example, while the other could be perpendicular to the floor. Not sure how to express it in more "technical" terms. I should be able to look at a molecule and to the other and say that they are the same (H2O for example, you can tell if 2 molecules are the same, even if oriented differently)

Comment: @Rook Being the first time I do this, I am not sure if just comparing line by line each of the vertices is enough. Although if you have a mesh in a different orientation, that set of vertices won't match 1:1.
I am looking for alternate ways to recognize a mesh, by shape you can say, independently from their orientation

Comment: Depending on the shapes you're trying to compare, you may be able to do something fairly straightforward, like compute a minimal bounding box over each shape, and use the differences in position, orientation and size of the respective boxes to compute a transform that should align the two and make comparison more straightfoward (eg. triangle by triangle). This won't work for objects that can be rotated within the bounding box though (eg. a sphere or a cylinder, etc).

Comment: I see, quite involved as process; is there any library that is able to do that, or do I have to write my own implementation? Thanks!